# UIImageView interactions

Tags: iphone, image, facebook, uiimageview

I am working on an app in which I want similar kind of functionality as that of WebMD body image.

1. How can I identify which part of image is touched in an optimal way? Do I have to slice the image according to requirements?
2. How can I add some tags into the image? Similar to the facebook photo upload functionality in iphone.

Answer (score 1):

You need some way to figure out what the user touched, or tried to touch.

You might use a list of annotation-like objects, where each object has a location. When the user touches the image, you'll need to find the annotation in the list that's closest to the touch location and react appropriately. The "optimal" way to do that is probably to use a quad tree. For an iPhone app, though, the number of touchable points is probably pretty small (several dozen?), and a brute force search through the list will probably be more than fast enough.

Another option would be to overlay a transparent view on top of your image for each region that you want the user to be able to touch. Doing this would also make it simple to draw a "tag" at each of those locations.

Comment: Thanks caleb! But about your first approach te app is not on iphone it's on ipad so the number of regions and annotations will be pretty much. I think I will try to follow the second approach. Let's c how it goes.